# Cannot retrieve cookies from react request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cookies

Here is my react code:

```
axios.get('http://localhost:5000/check').then(() => {
      axios.post('http://localhost:5000/cookie', null, { withCredentials: true });
    });
```

backend node js:

```
import express, { Application, Request, Response } from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';

const app: Application = express();

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(cors({ credentials: true, origin: 'http://localhost:3000' }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get('/check', (req, res) => {
  res.cookie('token', 'asdasd3123123', { httpOnly: true });
  res.send(200);
});

app.post('/cookie', (req: Request, res) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(req.cookies));
  res.send();
});

app.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log('Server running on port 5000');
});
```

The cookie is recieved in the response however is not set in the browser and when I log the request.cookies an empty object is printed.

[image]

Comment: Your cookies are not get set in your client?

Comment: They are not set in the client its one thing. Also I can't get the cookie in the backend(it is supposed to be carried to each request).

Comment: Mind if I give a solution with using express-session? So how express-session works is it creates a server side cookie stores that session within mongoDB automatically when the cookie is sent to client and also sets that cookie in react app flagging it as httpOnly?

Comment: I would prefer to know why this doesn't work.. but you are welcome to suggest. Thanks for the effort 

Comment: With this bug here I would not be of much help I have never used **cookie parser**, But with **express-session** this is more industry standard

Answer (score 1):

**Firstly you will need the following packages**

`npm i express-session connect-mongodb-session` or yarn add express-session connect-mongodb-session

**Now that we have packages that we need to setup our mongoStore and express-session middleware:**

```
//Code in server.js/index.js (Depending on your server entry point)
import expressSession from "express-session";
import MongoDBStore from "connect-mongodb-session";
import cors from "cors";
const mongoStore = MongoDBStore(expressSession);

const store = new mongoStore({
  collection: "userSessions",
  uri: process.env.mongoURI,
  expires: 1000,
});
app.use(
  expressSession({
    name: "SESS_NAME",
    secret: "SESS_SECRET",
    store: store,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false,
    cookie: {
      sameSite: false,
      secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
      maxAge: 1000,
      httpOnly: true,
    },
  })
);
```

**Now the session middleware is ready but now you have to setup cors to accept your ReactApp so to pass down the cookie and have it set in there by server**

```
//Still you index.js/server.js (Server entry point)

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    methods: ["POST", "PUT", "GET", "OPTIONS", "HEAD"],
    credentials: true,
  })
);
```

**Now our middlewares are all setup now lets look at your login route**

```
router.post('/api/login', (req, res)=>{
    //Do all your logic and now below is how you would send down the cooki

    //Note that "user" is the retrieved user when you were validating in logic
    // So now you want to add user info to cookie so to validate in future
    const sessionUser = {
       id: user._id,
       username: user.username,
       email: user.email,
    };
    //Saving the info req session and this will automatically save in your     mongoDB as configured up in sever.js(Server entry point)
    request.session.user = sessionUser;

    //Now we send down the session cookie to client
    response.send(request.session.sessionID);

})
```

**Now our server is ready but now we have to fix how we make request in client so that this flow can work 100%:**

**Code below: React App/ whatever fron-tend that your using where you handling logging in**

```
//So you will have all your form logic and validation and below
//You will have a function that will send request to server 

const login = () => {
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append("username", username);
    data.append("password", password);

    axios.post("http://localhost:5000/api/user-login", data, {
      withCredentials: true, // Now this is was the missing piece in the client side 
    });
};
```

**Now with all this you have now server sessions cookies as httpOnly**

Comment: Thanks for the reply, what exactly the advantage of this method?

Comment: So why I prefer using express-session and finding it to being advantageous for **me**, is because I have the ability to store all my users session in DB automatically once that session is created and furthermore, making it easy for me to manage all my users sessions and if for some reason I end up needing  that data for user sessions data for specific platform I have the data that I need, with express session I can also count the number of visits a user makes in my platform with just some simple if block and one line of code in so you see there's a lot you can do.

Answer (score 0):

had to include `{ withCredentials: true }` in the first call ->

```
axios.get('http://localhost:5000/check', { withCredentials: true } ).then(() => {
      axios.post('http://localhost:5000/cookie', null, { withCredentials: true });
    });
```